# Codeigniter version 1.0 to current

Tags: codeigniter

So my website is using Codeigniter version 1.0 - Im wondering what it would take to update it to the current version or even migrate it over to laravel ?

The website is quite large as it is a Directory however we have not launched just yet.

Thanks
Jonathon

Comment: Follow the steps : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html ;)

Comment: you might want to take a section of the site and upgrade to codeigniter 2.2 first. make sure there are no big breaking changes for your app. then the upgrade to 3 will be a little smoother.

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup your files
2. Backup your database
3. Follow [steps](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) from the bottom to the top.